# Convert connection to a hidden Wi-Fi to the normal one on iPhone

Tags: iphone, network, wifi

There is a Wi-Fi network with hidden SSID saved in iPhone. The drawback of such networks is that each device will constantly broadcast its desire to connect to this network even if it is on the other side of the globe.

Therefore, the network setting in the access point will be changed to unhide the SSID.

Now there is a classical way to change the connection from hidden to the normal one: forget the hidden Wi-Fi, find it again as the normal one, enter password again and connect.

Such a way will delete all the network connection settings.

Is there a simpler way to go to iPhone Wi-Fi settings and just change some property like "try to connect even if the network is hidden". I didn't find such a setting.

Comment: Go into WiFi settings, and in the list of known networks, turn off auto join.  You’ll have to manually connect each time you’re in range.